# Google Workspace SCIM with GitHub

Tags: github, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace, scim

I'm looking for a solution to configure SCIM in Google Workspace (SSO is already configured by Google web app called GitHub Business) to provision users to the GitHub organization.
Unfortunately, it seems that the only way to do that is to use GitHub SCIM API.
Google workspace is not one of officially supported IdPs :/
How can I configure it correctly in Google Workspace?
Should I use some 3rd part app in Google to do that?

I contacted with GitHub support and they suggested to use GitHub SCIM API, but they can't guide me how to configure it by Google Workspace side. I also contacted with Google support, but they were not super helpful and basically didn't suggest any solution.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? if so - how?
We're looking for a way of doing the same thing at my company now.
We were thinking of raising an Azure AD instance that we'll somehow keep synced against our Google Workspace AD - and since Azure-SCIM-Github integration is supported it could work.